# General ODBC Error in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi am populating the data from MS Access By Using VBA i am using below mentioned code.if i am run the same code in MS 2007 then It run properly but if i am run the same code in MS 2003 it gives the "General ODBC Error" how to solve this problem Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim varConnection As String
Dim varSQL As String
Dim cal, cal1, x

 varConnection = "ODBC; DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=D:\Box\Generate.mdb;Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)}"
'
       varSQL = "SELECT * FROM Empdata"

       With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=varConnection, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("C7"))

               .CommandText = varSQL

               .Name = "Query-39008"

               .Refresh BackgroundQuery = False
       End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the code button (the one with 0101) to create code blocks.

Comment: This is a question about automating Excel, right? If so, why isn't there an Excel tag? Likewise, the code is incompletel, as it could only run inside Excel, since ActiveSheet is a child of the Excel Application object, and unqualified, is usable in VBA only inside Excel.

Comment: -1 for bad tagging and lack of explicit mention of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Hi now my code is perfectly run in the 2003 format also:Just I want Share my idea with you,
Create the New Data Source Connection By using the following Steps

1 ) Choose  Start - >Control Panel ->Administrative Tools

2 ) Select Data Source (ODBC) icon

3 ) In The Data Source Administrator Dialog Box  Click Add Button

4 ) Select the Driver Click Finish Button

5 ) Give the DNS Name (user Define) . Select the Database By Click the Select Button

I am recording the macro through (Tools  -> Macros - Record macros) in my MS 2003 excel Sheet Before Import the data from the DB,

Steps to be followed to import the data from DB.

1 ) Select the Cell Where you Want to paste the data.

2 ) Choose from the Excel Menu : Data - > import External Data - > import Data

3 ) In the Select Data Source Dialog Box Select the New sources button

4 ) Select ODBC DNS ,click next

5 ) Select Data Source Table click next

6 ) Select the Table  from the List Click Finish Button

7 )  In the Select Data Source Dialog Box Select the DNS Source Name then click ok Button

8 ) Now Stop The Macros , Go To the View Code , You get the full code for data import connection, alter the path depends upon your program

Comment: You should really do a better job of writing your question and assigning tags to it. This is an Excel question, yet nowhere in your question nor in the tags does it say that explicitly. It's only the code that reveals this.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in 2003, but of course I had to change the connection string.  I can't believe the connection string would care what version you're using, but here's something you can do.  Create the query table through the UI (Data - Get External Data - New Database Quer), then go to the Immediate Window (Alt+F11, Control+G) and type

```
?ActiveCell.QueryTables.Connection
```

and see what you get.  If it doesn't match the connection string you have in your code, that may be a clue as to why it's working in one and not the other.

Comment: thank u for your reply but i enter the ?ActiveCell.QueryTables.Connection in the immediate window but the reply is " Object Does not Support this property or method " can you explain in Detail what are the changes are you did in the connection string

Comment: My D: drive is a DVD, so I couldn't use your connection string.  I created a QueryTable manually and looked at the connection string, then put it in your code and ran it to see if it was something else going on.  IN 2007, I think you need ActiveCell.ListObject.QueryTable.Connection, but I assumed you would be doing this in 2003.  My connection string is
ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=S:\AIMUSA\Accounting\AIMMRP.mdb;DefaultDir=S:\AIMUSA\Accounting;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;